How do I compile okular for windows using MSYS2 mingw64?
KDE offers a pre-compiled okular for windows in their site, but I found it to be rather slow and buggy, specially with relation to pen input generating zigzagged, spiky lines; a bug that appears to have been reported at least since 2020 (Windows only bug). I was trying to compile okular from source using MSYS2, but there appears to be no way to do so, I was trying to use Windows copilot to try to guide me with each error that appeared while trying to compile okular, and also to not make anyone here waste time if it could be solved that way.
But, although by following the proposed solution of copilot I was getting each time a new error, It was also true that it seemed to be requiring me to compile a never ending stream of pre-requisites for compiling okular, including perl modules like JSON-XS-4.03.
If anyone knows how to compile okular in windows could you please tell me? It clearly is possible since they offer a executable for windows on their site.
I was thinking of using this digital pen bug in okular to train my programming skills, this seems like a difficult problem that would also be usefull to be solved, I quite like KDE software and okular is very flexible with the range of accepted files it can read, and with its customization options. But I think that for the time being I will try some alternatives first like MuPDF or something...
